# Using generic email address for account registration

Tags: communication, productivity

Up till now, we've used admin@company.com in the past for all vendor account profiles. But it was also utilized for NOC alerts and became a virtual catch-all for a slurry of notifications. We are migrating mail hosts, so I was considering creating something separate for hosted account profiles (ex: profiles@company.xyz)

Question: anyone have any suggestion for best practices regarding company account registrations or input from past experiences?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you setup one main email account for *all* your vendors, and you are having issues sorting it out?

Comment: There was a single email that was originally meant for inbound NOC alerts (firewall logs, outage notices, etc). It later became the default mailbox for new account registrations also. Now I am trying to assign people to monitor/manage these accounts, so I'd like to compartmentalize them. I just know that, regardless of what solution I choose, I am unlikely to get another chance like this so I wanted to get some input so I can do it right the first (possibly only) time. (note: this is IMAP email >_< no shared folders)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about freelancing.

Comment: I looked for stack related to business operations, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting up secondary mailbox for corp accounts under a sub-domain email! Actually starting to roll this out to further compartmentalize and uniquely identify our email-based notification system.